# C# FolderBrowserDialog - how to include shared folders

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, vsto, folderbrowserdialog

I create a FolderBrowserDialog as follows (only an excerpt -not complete code):

```
   string tempSetWorkingPath = null;
    try
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog folderDlg = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();

        folderDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
        folderDlg.Description = "Selected your working folder. This is where your PDF files will be saved.";
        folderDlg.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
        folderDlg.SelectedPath = (Convert.ToString(WorkingPath).Trim().Length == 0) ? ((int)Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer).ToString() : WorkingPath;

        if (folderDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            tempSetWorkingPath = folderDlg.SelectedPath;
        }
        else
        {
            tempSetWorkingPath = "";
        }
    }
```

...

The code works well, except the only folders that are showing are the local folders. Users have DropBox and OneDrive shared folders on their systems and to select one of those directories, the user needs to cycle through the windows user directories and select the folder from there. On some systems I have seen over the last few months, I've seen the DropBox and OneDrive directories appear below the DeskTop directory ... but I have not, despite hours of searching - found a way to achive that.

How can I achieve that?

MTIA

DWE

Comment: I believe it depends on system version - starting from win 8 those folders should be listed under desktop.

Comment: @Mailosz - if you post your comment as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it .. changing the line folderDlg.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer; to folderDlg.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop; ... works like a dream ... thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Given I have observed a large number of queries posted here and elsewhere regarding the inclusion of the directories, including shared directories and given the response by @ Mailosz, it seems that the [root folder property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.rootfolder?view=netframework-4.7.2) of the folder dialog holds the key - *it Gets or sets the root folder where the browsing starts from* and thats what my code was missing.

The full code to the function referred to in my question appears below, in the event it assists someone else.

```
/// <summary>
/// presents the user with a folder dialog
/// Returns a full qualified directory chosen by the user
/// </summary>
/// <param name="WorkingPath">if a fully qualified directory name is provided, then the folder structure in the folder dialog will open to the directory selected</param>
/// <returns>Returns a full qualified directory chosen by the user or if no directory was chosen, an empty string</returns>
public string SetWorkingPath(string WorkingPath)
{
    string tempSetWorkingPath = null;
    try
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog folderDlg = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
        // check our proposed working path and if its valid
        if((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(WorkingPath) && (WorkingPath != null)))
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(WorkingPath))
                  WorkingPath = string.Empty;
        }
        else // if we are empty or null set us to empty
        {
            WorkingPath = string.Empty;
        }
        folderDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
        folderDlg.Description = "Please select your working folder. This is where your PDF files will be saved.";
        folderDlg.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop;//.MyComputer;
        folderDlg.SelectedPath = (Convert.ToString(WorkingPath).Trim().Length == 0) ? ((int)Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer).ToString() : WorkingPath;

        if (folderDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // make sure we have a backslash on the end of our directory string
            tempSetWorkingPath = PathAddBackslash(folderDlg.SelectedPath);
        }
        else
        {
            // return an empty string
            tempSetWorkingPath = string.Empty;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        tempSetWorkingPath = string.Empty;

        throw (ex);
    }

    return tempSetWorkingPath;
}
public string PathAddBackslash(string path)
{
    // They're always one character but EndsWith is shorter than
    // array style access to last path character. Change this
    // if performance are a (measured) issue.
    string separator1 = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString();
    string separator2 = Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar.ToString();

    // Trailing white spaces are always ignored but folders may have
    // leading spaces. It's unusual but it may happen. If it's an issue
    // then just replace TrimEnd() with Trim(). Tnx Paul Groke to point this out.
    path = path.TrimEnd();

    // Argument is always a directory name then if there is one
    // of allowed separators then I have nothing to do.
    if (path.EndsWith(separator1) || path.EndsWith(separator2))
        return path;

    // If there is the "alt" separator then I add a trailing one.
    // Note that URI format (file://drive:\path\filename.ext) is
    // not supported in most .NET I/O functions then we don't support it
    // here too. If you have to then simply revert this check:
    // if (path.Contains(separator1))
    //     return path + separator1;
    //
    // return path + separator2;
    if (path.Contains(separator2))
        return path + separator2;

    // If there is not an "alt" separator I add a "normal" one.
    // It means path may be with normal one or it has not any separator
    // (for example if it's just a directory name). In this case I
    // default to normal as users expect.
    return path + separator1;
}
```